# "Too Many Arguments" in If-Statement

Tags: excel

The following if statement is reporting "Too Many Arguments"

```
=IF(AND(G4="Other Revenue",(E4>200000)),("Pass"),IF(AND(G4="Trading Revenue",(E4>200000)),("Pass")),IF(AND(G4="NII",(E4>200000)),("Pass"),("Fail")))
```

Any idea why?

Comment: probably too many comas.  you probably have something like IF condition check, true result, false result, something is not supposed to be here)

Comment: nope, it wa a case where you had a bracket in the wrong spot.  move the 1 bracket from after the second pass to the end of your equation.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(G4="Other Revenue",E4>200000),"Pass", IF(AND(G4="Trading Revenue",E4>200000),"Pass",IF(AND(G4="NII",E4>200000),"Pass","Fail")))
```

Also please don't use so many unnecessary parentheses. You don't need to cover simple string expressions in parentheses....

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra bracket after the second "pass" which is causing the function to terminate early. Try this instead:

```
=IF(AND(G4="Other Revenue",(E4>200000)),"Pass",IF(AND(G4="Trading Revenue",(E4>200000)),"Pass",IF(AND(G4="NII",(E4>200000)),"Pass","Fail")))
```

---

Issue with your formula:

```
=IF(AND(G4="Other Revenue",(E4>200000)),("Pass"),IF(AND(G4="Trading Revenue",(E4>200000)),("Pass")),IF(AND(G4="NII",(E4>200000)),("Pass"),("Fail")))
                                                                                                  ^
                                                                                                  |
                                                                                              This fella.
```